# Access Image control in a dynamic pivot item

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, pivot

I have a pivot control with dynamicaly generated items, pointing to a list of objects.

The pivot item template contains an image control that is bound to Uri property in the objects provided.

here is the line from the pivot item template:

`<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="660" Width="460"/>`

I discovered i need to access the Image control inside the generated pivot items, so i can explicitly set its source to null after i use it, otherwise it will not free the memory and the app exceeds the 90 mb requirement.

So for a given pivot index, how can i reference the Image control inside the pivot item?

Comment: what does it mean 'after I use it'?

Comment: @Robort: sorry i wasn't clear, i mean after the user moved to another pivot item, i don't need it anymore, so i should free its memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled the "Unloading" event of the image, and used it to set the source to null.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a name in the template and then use `PivotItem.FindName(string name)` to find the `Image` control. You can preform an explicit type cast for the object returned, so it will be an actual `Image` control where you can manipulate the contents.

Although I think that there are major optimization problems on some other end if your images (in app) are taking 90+ MB of memory.

Comment: I can't access the PivotItem,  pivot.items[i] returns the object from the collection, not a PivotItem.